# How to detect and echo the last vowel in a word?

Tags: php, detect, multibyte

```
$word = "Acrobat" (or Apple, Tea etc.)
```

How can I detect and echo the last vowel of a given word with php? I tried preg_match function, google'd for hours but couldn't find a proper solution.

There can be multibyte letters like ü, ö in the string.

Comment: you guys seem to miss the point, you won't help this guy out by doing his homeworks, trying is fun you know

Comment: Yes, but it's fun for me too.

Comment: So far 3/4 answers have done this guy's homework for him. On a question like this the best he should get are pointer to helpful functions or doc pages. Like [preg_match](http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), [preg_match_all](http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php), and [explode](http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

Comment: keep in mind, if you posted what have you tried, you will get more significant answers.

Comment: I think SO isn't about working for others but about helping others, maybe it should be more explicit before posting a question that community WON'T do the job for you. As for people that gets reputation by doing homeworks, I think they should think a little bit more about the message they deliver to the OP by doing it (ie: you don't have to try yourself, just ask on SO).

Comment: Getting 4 completely different answers might help teach something too, about the flexibility of PHP

Comment: I only partly agree with the whole homework argument. But I highly doubt you spent hours looking for a proper solution when the first result in google for "php get last vowel" returns basically exactly what you need. Sometimes answering trivial things like this can be just fun, so who cares if it is homework. We get wrapped up in serious programming and entry level stuff like this is like a mini vacation relatively speaking.

Comment: Thanks for the answers and comments. I'm 35 years old and have no intend to become a PHP guru. I have a Wordpress site (that CMS that doesnt require much PHP knowledge, you know) and need a simple code. Believe me I google'd for hours and learned preg_replace function and tried many examples. But no one could coved my specific question. I thought it would take seconds for an expert and then I could go and sleep as very late here. I understand what you are criticizing and your comments will help the community. I'll try to be more specific and try to tell what methods or codes I tried next time.

Comment: Dear Kai Qing, if you know what you are searching and search with right words then Google is a gold mine. Otherwise it doesn't help. I have a terrible English, little Php knowledge, so life is a little hard for me :)

Comment: This was my first question. Community immediately attacked with negative votes and comments but they helped, I'll be more careful, thanks.

Comment: I think you should indicate that you're looking for a multibyte solution so that your question will not be downvoted as much.

Comment: You are right, @inhan. But I didn't estimate that it would differ. BTW, thank you very much for your time and tolerance again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a multibyte safe version of catching the last vowel in a string.

```
$arr = array(
    'Apple','Tea','Strng','queue',
    'asartä','nő','ağır','NOËL','gør','æsc'
);

/*  these are the ones I found in character viewer
    in Mac so these vowels can be extended. don't
    forget to add both lower and upper case versions
    of new ones because personally I wouldn't rely
    on the i (case insensitive) flag in the pattern
    for multibyte characters.
*/
$vowels =
    'aàáâãāăȧäảåǎȁąạḁẚầấẫẩằắẵẳǡǟǻậặæǽǣ' .
    'AÀÁÂÃĀĂȦÄẢÅǍȀȂĄẠḀẦẤẪẨẰẮẴẲǠǞǺẬẶÆǼǢ' .
    'EÈÉÊẼĒĔĖËẺĚȄȆẸȨĘḘḚỀẾỄỂḔḖỆḜ' .
    'eèéêẽēĕėëẻěȅȇẹȩęḙḛềếễểḕḗệḝ' .
    'IÌÍÎĨĪĬİÏỈǏỊĮȈȊḬḮ' .
    'iìíîĩīĭıïỉǐịįȉȋḭḯ' .
    'OÒÓÔÕŌŎȮÖỎŐǑȌȎƠǪỌØỒỐỖỔȰȪȬṌṐṒỜỚỠỞỢǬỘǾŒ' .
    'oòóôõōŏȯöỏőǒȍȏơǫọøồốỗổȱȫȭṍṏṑṓờớỡởợǭộǿœ' .
    'UÙÚÛŨŪŬÜỦŮŰǓȔȖƯỤṲŲṶṴṸṺǛǗǕǙỪỨỮỬỰ' .
    'uùúûũūŭüủůűǔȕȗưụṳųṷṵṹṻǖǜǘǖǚừứữửự'
;

// set necessary encodings
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');

// and loop
foreach ($arr as $word) {

    $vow = mb_ereg_replace('[^'.$vowels.']','',$word);
    // get rid of all consonants (non-vowels in this pattern)
    $lastVw = mb_substr($vow,-1);
    // and get the last one from the remaining vowels

    if (empty($lastVw))
    // it evaluates this line when there's no vowel in the string
        echo "there's no vowel in <b>\"$word\"</b>." . PHP_EOL;
    else
    // and vice versa
        echo "last vowel in <b>\"$word\"</b> is " .
        "<span style=\"color:#F00\">{$lastVw}</span>" . PHP_EOL;    
}
```

Here's the output.

> last vowel in **"Apple"** is ***e***
>   last vowel in **"Tea"** is ***a***
>   there's no vowel in **"Strng"**.
>   last vowel in **"queue"** is ***e***
>   last vowel in **"asartä"** is ***ä***
>   last vowel in **"nő"** is ***ő***
>   last vowel in **"ağır"** is ***ı***
>   last vowel in **"NOËL"** is ***Ë***
>   last vowel in **"gør"** is ***ø***
>   last vowel in **"æsc"** is ***æ***

Answer (score 2):

```
$word = "Acrobat";
$vowels = array_intersect(str_split($word), array('A','E','I','O','U','a','e','i','o','u'));
echo array_pop($vowels);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function last_vowel($word) {
  for ($i = strlen($word) - 1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
      switch (strtolower($word[$i])) {
        case 'a': case 'e': case 'i': case 'o': case 'u': case 'y':
          return $word[$i];
      }
  }
  return null;
}

echo last_vowel("Apple");
```

Answer (score 0):

use the method str_split()

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php

this will transform your string into an array then you can use the index of the array in finding the 
first and last letter of your string.

-Array[0] is the first letter
*Array[total number of letters - 1] is the last letter.

After getting the first and last elements in the array, the mapping begins. eg:
    if(letter=="a"||letter=="A")
     echo "Apple";

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

I would say Ed or Mark's answers are definitely more efficient, but if you want an example of a recursive function here it is:

```
$word = "stellar";

function lastVowel($word)
{
    $vowels = array('a','e','i','o','u');
    $letter = substr($word, strlen($word) - 1);
    if(in_array(strtolower($letter), $vowels))
        return $letter;
    else
    {
        if(strlen($word) > 0)
            return lastVowel(substr($word, 0, strlen($word) - 1));
        else
            return "no vowels";
    }
}

echo lastVowel($word);
```

Mind you, there are better ways to do this. Just giving a specific example, not necessarily the "best" one.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) for this task.

```
$arr = array(
    'Apple','Tea','Strng','queue'
);

foreach ($arr as $word) {

    preg_match('~[aeiou](?=[^aeiou]*$)~i',$word,$m);

    if (empty($m)) echo "there's no vowel in \"$word\".";
    else echo "last vowel in \"$word\" is <b style=\"color:#F00\">{$m[0]}</b>";
    echo PHP_EOL;   
}
```

This will output

> last vowel in "Apple" is **e**
>   last vowel in "Tea" is **a**
>   there's no vowel in "Strng".
>   last vowel in "queue" is **e**

Comment: Hello inhan, I'm not an expert so although the answers above may be great, I checked your solution and it worked great. The only problem is that there are ü, ö letters in my language and this code outputs some strange characters.

Comment: @CarlisleHolm Then you need to introduce the pattern with all possible vowels. I'll update my answer to make it easier for you to add these.

Comment: @CarlisleHolm I'm posting my alternative answer as a separate one because the approach there is pretty different.