# Change array value when next one starts with vowel

Tags: php, arrays

I have a function, which should create many conjugation tables with french verbs.

How do I change always the first value of $french_personal_pronouns from "je" to "j'", when the next value after french_personal_pronouns[0] starts where the first letter is vowel (a,e,i,o,u)?

```
<?php
$french_personal_pronouns = array("je", "tu", "il", "nous", "vous", "ils");
$aimer = array ("aime", "aimes", "aime", "aimons", "aimez", "aiment");
$dire = array ("dis", "dit", "disons", "dites", "disent");


echo "$french_personal_pronouns[0] $aimer[1]"."<br>"; // result je aime -> should be j'aime
echo "$french_personal_pronouns[0] $dire[1]"."<br>";
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How you loop this to create a proper application structure is up to you, but in your specific example you can look up the next value before you output it and compare it to your vowels array.

I've written a simple vowel check function and wrapped the comparisons in another function for ease of readability. [Here's a demo](https://eval.in/178006) too:

```
// Determine if a letter is a vowel
// @return bool true/false
function isVowel($letter) {
    return in_array(strtolower($letter), array('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'));
}

function outputFrench($word_one, $word_two) {
    // if the first letter of $word_two is a vowel...
    if(isVowel($word_two{0}))
        // use the first letter of $word_one with an apostrophe and all of $word_two
        $output = $word_one{0} . '\'' . $word_two;
    else
        // other wise combine the words with a space in between
        $output = $word_one . ' ' . $word_two;

    return $output;
}

echo outputFrench($french_personal_pronouns[0], $aimer[0]); // j'aime
```

Comment: I've got to say though - I don't know anything about the French language but I'm guessing you won't be able to rely on this kind of function to correctly combine your words in all cases... good luck though.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Only one problem with other pronoms except je for example `echo outputFrench($french_personal_pronouns[1], $aimer[1]); // t'aimes is wrong, should be tu aimes`.

Comment: As I mentioned, this example won't suit all your needs. Your requirement that the pronoun should be shortened to e.g. `t'` when the following word starts with a vowel is satisfied in that example you've just given. You'll need to write some pretty long and complex logic here to fulfill every single instance of language generation. E.g. there is no difference between `je aime (j'aime)` and `tu aimes (t'aimes)` in *this function*, so you need to tell it where it should catch these exceptions and what to do with them

Comment: Alright, no problem. Then I will only use this function for the first pronoms "je".

Comment: A better idea would be to categorize your pronouns into groups, and perform certain actions based on that group. E.g. there might be other pronouns like je that may require the same action to be performed - if you group them then you can make one call for both those cases. You could then add new functions to be performed for other types of pronouns e.g. the "tu" group might just return word one and two with a space in the middle, etc.

Comment: Can you add support to vowels like é, because, then the function need UTF-8 support, because it don't work with an addition value like 'é'in the vowel array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59077/discussion-between-grischa-and-scrowler).

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14270009/2812842) would help you to implement a universal solution.